# Does gmapping resize the map if required?

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using gmapping. The default map-size is a 4000x4000 cells (200m x 200m) occupancy grid map stored in a 1x16,000,000 1D array.

What happens if I make the default map-size a 200x200 cells map (10m x 10m) and the map has to be extended in action?
Does gmapping do this itself or would this be a problem?

Thanks for your help.
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226782/does-gmapping-resize-the-map-if-required?/) by [Alex1209](https://answers.ros.org/users/25356/alex1209/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, Gmapping allows for map growth. I also believe it uses a tiled map representation behind the scenes (see [HierarchicalArray2D](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/gmapping/html/classGMapping_1_1HierarchicalArray2D.html)), so it should be multiple 1D arrays instead of one (with additional ones being added when the map grows).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex1209](https://answers.ros.org/users/25356/alex1209/) on 2016-02-16**:
Thanks for the quick answer.

Your answer brings up another question to me:
The published topic "map" is of type "[occupancy grid](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html)" which uses int8[] for data.
Is the HierarchicalArray2D also used there? Or only for internal calculation?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-02-16**:
The hierarchical grid is only used internally. It is converted to a standard ROS occupancy grid message.

**Comment by [Alex1209](https://answers.ros.org/users/25356/alex1209/) on 2016-02-16**:
Thanks a lot for your quick answers.